# Correct rows retrieved with group query, but need more columns with unique data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query that returns the exact rows that are needed.

```
SELECT id_prod, item_type, id_item, max(date_time) maxdate
FROM items_pricing 
WHERE id_prod IN (5,6) AND item_type IN (2,3)
GROUP BY id_prod, item_type, id_item
ORDER BY id_prod, item_type, id_item
```

However, I also need other unique columns (i.e. id, list, cost) from those same rows that cannot be in this query because it would affect the row retrieved because of the GROUP clause. How can I modify the query to add the additional columns?

Comment: There could be several different `ID`s, for example, for one your row in this query. You should describe a way, how to choose and display them.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc)? The most efficient way of doing this is likely going to depend on your specific vendor.

Comment: Thanks. At this point, I will need this type of query with MySql and Sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT ip.* FROM
items_pricing ip
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id_prod, item_type, id_item, max(date_time) maxdate 
    FROM items_pricing 
    WHERE id_prod IN (5,6) AND item_type IN (2,3) 
    GROUP BY id_prod, item_type, id_item 
    ORDER BY NULL
) sq ON sq.maxdate = ip.date_time;
```

For other ways to do this, there are more examples [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html). (The link is to the MySQL manual, but it can be applied to other DBMS, too, since it uses just standard SQL)

Comment: The INNER JOIN did the trick. Thanks. I only had to add the rest of the columns from the second SELECT statement to the ON statement at the end. Thanks for the help! (Too new to vote up...sorry.)

Comment: @Rocky Well, then feel free to do so :-) (by clicking the check on the left of my answer).

Comment: I will get all this figured out someday. I have used this website so many times as a guest, but now...